# JWT Exists Check -- Where To Do It?

Tags: angularjs, jwt

I have a Login Service that is handling the initial JWT creation and I am getting the user data just fine out of the payload.

The problem that I am having is where do I place the code to check to make sure the JWT exists and is valid on every page change?  I already have an Auth Service with a function called `isAuthed` and I just want to check to make sure that it is not false.

My initial idea was to put this code in the `App.run`, but I am not having any luck with it.

```
if (authSvc.getToken() === undefined || !authSvc.isAuthed(authSvc.getToken())) {
    $window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/#/login";
else {
    // Continue to run the rest of the .run function.
}
```

The first check in the conditional above calls a function that pulls the JWT from local storage.  So, we want to make sure it is not undefined.  The next check is to see if that token is valid.  If either of those conditions fail, obviously route the user back to the login page.

What I am trying to do is ensure that if someone hits something like `localhost:3000/#/app/dashboard` that they are getting kicked back to the login page.

Should I be handling this via the `resolve` parameter in the route instead as I do have the parent `app` that I could put the `resolve` in and then it should check for authentication for all childs?

I have seen too many different ways for checking for authentication for JWT that I really just need a clear cut answer on the best practice here.

AuthService.js

```
function AuthService($window) {
    var self = this;

    self.parseJwt = function(token) {
        var base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
        var base64 = base64Url.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/');
        return JSON.parse($window.atob(base64));
    }

    self.saveToken = function(token) {
        $window.localStorage['jwtToken'] = token;
    }

    self.getToken = function() {
        return $window.localStorage['jwtToken'];
    }

    self.isAuthed = function() {
        var token = self.getToken();
        if(token) {
            var params = self.parseJwt(token);
            return Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) <= params.exp;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    self.logout = function() {
        $window.localStorage.removeItem('jwtToken');
    }
}

App.service('authSvc', AuthService);
```

Config.js (Routes part)

```
//
// App Routes
// -----------------------------------
$stateProvider

    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: basepath('login.html')
    })

    .state('register', {
        url: '/register',
        templateUrl: basepath('register.html')
    })

    .state('recover', {
        url: '/recover-password',
        templateUrl: basepath('recover.html')
    })

    .state('app', {
        url: '/app',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: basepath('app.html'),
        controller: 'AppController'
    })

    .state('app.users', {
        url: '/users',
        templateUrl: basepath('users.html'),
        controller: 'UserController',
        title: 'Users'
    })

    .state('app.projects', {
        url: '/projects',
        templateUrl: basepath('projects.html'),
        controller: 'ProjectController',
        title: 'Projects'
    })

    .state('app.dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: basepath('dashboard.html'),
        title: 'Dashboard'
    });
```

AuthIntercepterFactory.js

```
function AuthInterceptorFactory(API, authSvc) {
    return {
        // automatically attach Authorization header
        request: function(config) {
            var token = authSvc.getToken();
            if(config.url.indexOf(API) === 0 && token) {
                config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
            }

            return config;
        },

        // If a token was sent back, save it
        response: function(res) {
            if(res.config.url.indexOf(API) === 0 && res.data.token) {
                authSvc.saveToken(res.data.token);
            }

            return res;
        },

        responseError: function(res) {
            if(res.status === 401 || res.status == 403) {
                $window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/#/login";
            }
        }
    }
}

App.service('authInterceptor', AuthInterceptorFactory);
```

Please let me know if you need any additional code from other files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you should build an interceptor and check it there, at the same place you should check for 401 and 402 errors

more about interceptors here:

https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.3/docs/api/ng/service/$http

they will basically "intercept" your http traffic providing success and error functions that allows you to inspect and transform the calls to be made(request interceptors), and to check the responses (response interceptors)

Comment: Hey Dayan.  I added my AuthInterceptorFactory.js file to the initial post at the bottom.  Could tell me where you would add it?  Not trying to be ungrateful for the advice, I am just looking for a bit more direction of where to actually place it.  Are you talking about checking it prior to every request made in the interceptor?

Comment: this line in the docs should throw some light to your question
`$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');`
if not let me give you a clue, where are providers available? you got it during .config() of your app

Comment: I've been working on an Angular 1.x project and appreciate your cluing us in on the Interceptor. I've been able to successfully generate a token and send a response header on my initial login/registration/dashboard requests, but subsequent API calls are causing me 401 headaches. Will try and utilize an interceptor to check for token first and see if I can find resolution. Lots of search querying and nobody discussed this; much appreciated!

Comment: glad to help. i have not work with ng for a while now, but let a comment if you need clarification on anything else i might be able to help